# Which is better to work upon among Async Task, Runnable and Handler in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, runnable

while working on thread in android I came across runnable and handler. My question is, what is the better option to use `AsyncTask` or `Thread` (or `Runnable`) for multi-threading. I found using `AsyncTask` very easy and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my concern ,if you need to run short operations you can use AsyncTask.To keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as **Executor**, **ThreadPoolExecutor** and **FutureTask**.You can also refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i think you are right because i took reference from other sources and they said the same things. for longer operations java.util.concurrent package is more suitable than AsyncTask

Comment: If you need alternatives, take a look at:
[http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/painless-threading.html](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 2):

### Async Task

- AsyncTask was written to provide a convenient, easy-to-use way to achieve background processing in Android apps, without worrying too much about the low-level details(threads, message loops etc). It provides callback methods that help to schedule tasks and also to easily update the UI whenever required.
- AsyncTask runs a set of actions in a separate thread, can show progress during its work and show notification when the task is completed.
- However, there is a limit to the number of jobs that can be scheduled using AsyncTasks.

### Runnable

- Runnable is a command that can be performed. You should run in a separate thread. Also you should develop a logic in this case how to update progress and how to notify when the task is finished.

### Handler

- Handler is more transparent of all and probably gives you more freedom; so if you want more control on things you would choose Handler.
- Handler is a special class that can handle messages that are sent to the handler's thread.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask's advantage is that it can perform actions in a different thread than the UI thread using the doInBackground functions,and then return the output of the processing to the UI thread using the onPostExecute function. This is very important because only the UI thread can be used for UI related functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is more Efficient as it has Functions onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), onProgressUpdate() and doInBackground() functions. 
The doInBackground() function runs in a seperate thread where we can run intensive operations and you can update the progress of the running operation using onProgressUpdate(). and onPostExecute() function is called after the doInBackground() function finishes where you can dismiss the progress dialog if used. The Advantage here is you need not create a seperate thread as this class has functions for doing that.